# Convert a B-Spline into Bezier curves

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, spline, dxf, bspline

I have a B-Spline curve. I have all the knots, and the x,y coordinates of the Control Points.

I need to convert the B-Spline curve into Bezier curves.

My end goal is to be able to draw the shape on an html5 canvas element. The B-Spline is coming from a dxf file which doesn't support Beziers, while a canvas only supports Beziers.

I've found several articles which attempt to explain the process, however they are quite a bit over my head and really seem to be very theory intensive. I really need an example or step by step help.

Here's what I've found:
[(Explains B-Splines)](https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~david/Classes/CS430/Lectures/L-09_BSplines_NURBS.pdf),[(Converting to Beziers)](http://www.infogoaround.org/JBook/bstobez.html),[(Javascript Example)](http://www.maissan.net/articles/simulating-vines/2)

The last link is nice because it contains actual code, however it doesn't seem to take into account the weight assigned by the nodes. I think this is kind of important as it seems to influence whether the curve passes through a control point.

I can share my Nodes or Control Points if that would be useful. If someone would point me to a step-by-step procedure or help me with some psuedo(or actual)code, I would be so grateful.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted some of the information you have about the control points.  For example, are your points [x, y], [x, y, w], [xw, yw, zw, w], or something else?  Just post a small example of everything that defines a spline, that would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple Javascript implementation of Boehm's algorithm for cubic B-Splines a while back. It's a fairly straightforward implementation involving polar values, described here in section 6.3: [Computer Aided Geometric Design- Sederberg](http://tom.cs.byu.edu/~557/text/cagd.pdf)

If you're just interested in the implementation, I've linked the classes I wrote here: [bsplines.js](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/157117/bsplines.js)

Comment: The link to your bsplines.js is no longer working. Any chance you could reinstate it?

Answer (score 0):

This could be helpful  - https://github.com/Tagussan/BSpline

My project has moved on and I no longer need it, but this seems to be a pretty useful way to feed control points and have a curve drawn.

Comment: Also see [cardinal splines](https://github.com/epistemex/cardinal-spline-js) for a simple way to draw smooth curves

Comment: @TimSum The referenced GitHub project seems to render splines using raster technique. I suspect it is not converting to Bézier curve. I am still looking for a solution for me too.